# ¿Porque Oracle me rechaza la conexión al usar un usuario distinto a SYSTEM?

Tags: sql, oracle

Esto usando Oracle g11 para poder usar SQL. Al crear una conexión con el usuario "SYSTEM" todo va bien. Una vez dentro, trato de crear un usuario para poder usarlo con aplicaciones externas, el detalle es que los usuarios que creo no se logran conectar, pues cuando pruebo la conexión me retorna una excepción aparentemente por que el usuario o contraseña es incorrecto, pero se estan colocando las credenciales correctas.

Cuando entro al SYSTEM los usuarios si se logran visualizar, cuando los creo, les asigno roles de conexión y de recursos.

Las siguientes imagenes muestran como el usuario SYSTEM pone en estado "correcto" cuando pruebo la conexión, pero los usuarios que fueron creados por medio de SYSTEM no responden a la prueba de conexión.

[image: Conexión con SYSTEM (Todo correcto desde aqui)]

[image: Conexión con otro usuario (En un foro lei que los espacios afectan, pero no funciona con nigun otro usuario)]

**Así estoy creando los usuarios:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! estarass creando mal los usuarios??? nos mostras como los creaste y si cuando entras con system los ves?

Comment: Los usuarios si se ven desde System. Edite la pregunta para mostrar los pasos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Cuando creo una conexión con el usuario "SYSTEM" todo va bien, luego entro para crear un usuario nuevo (Esto con el fin de usarlo con una aplicacion externa)  pero ese usuario (Y todos los que he intentado crear) no responden a la prueba de conexión, ya que cuando pruebo la conexión, a diferencia de system, estos usuario retornan "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos" y no el estado "Correcto"  a pesar de que las credenciales que se colocan si son las correctas

Comment: Como nota adicional, ya reinicie mi computador (estoy en un localhost), tambien reinstale 2 veces Oracle y reinicie servicios de Oracle XE pero no he podido solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de estar investigando por muchos foros y documentación, me he dado cuenta de que el error sencillamente era un tema de distinción de mayusculas y minusculas (En el nombre de usuario, no la contraseña). En algunos lugares ya me habian compartido usar el siguiente comando de sqlplus para desactivar mayusculas y minusculas:

```
alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=FALSE;
```

Sin embargo, esto era para la conteraseña. Adjuntare una serie de posibles pasos para alguien que tenga este inconveniente bajo la suposición que olvido su contraseña, que el usuario esta en minusculas y que no tiene acceso desde SYSTEM (Ya que, primero tienes que conectarte al system para poder crear otro usuario).

1. Pimero intenta conectarte a SYSTEM con las credenciales que colocaste al instalar oracle. Si no la recuerdas o es incorrecta, puedes cambiarla abriendo un cmd o simbolo de sistema y escribir: `sqlplus / as sysdba`. Una vez dentro, cambias la contraseña del usuario system con  `alter user system identified by "admin";` en donde "admin" sera la nueva contraseña. Posiblemente hayas bloqueado el usuario con el exceso de intentos, entonces lo desbloqueas con `alter user system account unlock;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Como ya tienes la contraseña de SYSTEM, ahora crea una conexión con SYSTEM y la contraseña. Creas el usuario normal, pero **pon el usuario con mayusculas**, por ejemplo, en lugar de "Admin1" colocar "ADMIN1". Por su puesto que debes de otorgar rol de conexión y de recurso desde la pestaña de roles.
3. Esta vez si, prueba la conexión de nuevo, si no hay nigun factor adicional como el puerto, el listener o algo más, todo debe funcionar bien.

Eso fue lo que me solucionó el inconveniente.